# Writing ethernet packet to specific memory location?

Tags: c, tcp, fpga, ethernet, zynq

I will be really grateful if someone can point a way for me !

I want to design a system, which could accept accept data through TCP/IP protocol, Now as soon as the data is received I want to redirect this data to **specific memory location** and freeing the receive buffer for next coming packet and doing same this also. In my system there is only one dedicated connection from host to  my fpga board.

I am using LWIP.I am trying to understand how LWIP makes the descriptor list 
(I mean how a specific memory location is decided for this purpose as i have observed every time I initialize the program the rx_qbar  point to different location even without no packet is sent or received!!).

So my idea is I should have control the completed descriptor and when next buffer is in process I could copy the first buffer(i mean BD1 completed,Bd2 continuing,BD1 rx_buffer will be copied to my specified address), without interfering the ongoing transaction at receive port!. I will grateful if some can help me to understand this process at register level.

Comment: You should overthink the tags of this question, since it is more related to C programming.

Comment: You should explain the hardware you're using exactly.  Like, what network adapter, what FPGA, what host, and how it's all connected.